# Как склоняется слово "прообраз"?

Tags: морфология

Фраза такая: "В рассказе его убили, как и его прообраз(а)". Так вот, что-то не могу сообразить: как правильно? По идее, "прообраз" — предмет одушевленный, значит, должно быть окончание "-а"... Или нет?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если "прообраз" и "прототип" - одно и то же, то в значении " тот, кто послужил автору образцом для создания персонажа художественного  произведения" сущ. может быть одушевлённым, по ответу Грамоты.ру: Прототип – неодушевленное существительное в знач. «первоначальный образец, прообраз чего-л.»: вижу прототип нового оружия. В знач. «лицо, послужившее автору оригиналом для создания литературного образа» прототип может употребляться как  одушевленное существительное.
http://www.gramota.ru/spravka/buro/search_answer/?s=%EE%E4%F3%F8%E5%E2%EB.
А в сочетании с "убили", по-моему,не возможно, а только как одушевлённое.Убить можно только живое существо.Так что "В рассказе его убили, как и его прообраза" , но фраза действительно разговорная, нелитературная, как заметила EkaterinaKas...

Comment: Прототип и прообраз - синонимы, но не одно и то же. "Убили прообраза" звучит просто чудовищно.

Answer (score 2):

Прообраз - это неодушевлённое существительное. Обозначает "прообраз" не конкретного человека, животное и т. п., а представление автора образа об этом человеке, животном и пр..   Поэтому у одного и того же персонажа возможны сразу несколько прообразов, от каждого из которых взяли какую-то отдельную черту.

Так что, в вашем случае фраза будет звучать *В рассказе его убили, как и его прообраз*.

P.S. К вопросу это не относится, но из фразы получается, что в рассказе сперва убивают "его прообраз", а потом "его". Если прообраз убивали вне рассказа, то фразу лучше переделать.

Answer (score 1):

Пожалуйста, простите меня, но не могу не сказать: предложение построено неправильно. 
В рассказе никого не могут убить: это рассказ, а не город, лес, улица, переулок и т.п., где действительно может произойти убийство. Рассказ - это текст. Убить могут героя рассказа  при определённых обстоятельствах, в определённом месте, по определённой причине. 
Убить прообраз тоже невозможно. 
 По поводу Вашего вопроса. Слово ПРООБРАЗ - это существительное неодушевлённое, и поэтому в винительном падеже единственного числа оно имеет нулевое окончание: КОГО?ЧТО? прообраз.

Comment: >В рассказе никого не могут убить...  
  
НЕт. Это вполне нормально. "В рассказе" означает "согласно рассказу". Стяжение идет примерно по такой схеме:  
В рассказе повествуется, как его убивают на улице.   
В рассказе его убивают на улице.   
В рассказе его убивают.

Answer (score 1):

*Хотел комментировать, но решился на ответ.*

Тут явно вопрос об одушевленности. Есть такие слова, которые в разном контексте проявляют эту категорию по-разному (знаменитое "люблю [есть] раки", но "вижу раков"), у них есть какое-то "официальное" название, мне оно не понравилось - и я его забыл. Но суть от того не страдает.

Так вот.

Чудовищно звучит потому, что "прототип" обладает определенной степенью одушевленности, "прообраз" - нет.
В рассказе его убили, как и его прообраз - только так.
В рассказе его убили, как и его прототипа - возможно, если не рекомендуется.
В рассказе его убили, как и его прототип - возможно

А так ответ Людмилы - +1. 
И комментарий EkaterinaKas... - +1.

Вспомнил. Их называют "окказионально-одушевлённые". Не нравится потому, что как правило здесь нет окказиональности. Вопрос контекста или (реже) авторского выбора.

Comment: В  ответе  описка - исправьте  (  для  душевного  равновесия  ).

Comment: Не вижу. Где? У меня вообще случается "слепота" на свой текст.  
Поправил логическую несуразицу (был прототип вместо прообраза). Вы о ней?

Comment: Да. Я  посчитал,  что  это  у  вас  описка.

Comment: >Да. Я посчитал, что это у вас описка.  
  
Оговорка, так скажем. Описка - это когда буквы пропустил или перепутал. 
А тут заерундил в логике. Тоже, конечно, своего рода опечатка, но их другой серии, я на ней и внимания не обратил, когда *опечатку* искал.

Answer (score 0):

Склоняется, как неодуш. сущ. м.р. 2 склонения.

Answer (score 0):

ПРОТОТИП | Толковый словарь Ожегова

, -а, м. Реальное лицо как источник для создания художественного образа, героя. П. Анны Карениной.

ПРОТОТИП | Большой Энциклопедический словарь (БЭС)

-(греч. prototypon - прообраз) - реальная личность, послужившая автору первообразом при создании художественного образа.

ПРОТОТИП | Толковый словарь Даля

-м . греч. первообраз, начальный, основной образец, истинник. Прототипный, -типический, первообразный, первообразцовый.